# How to compare two rows in a table in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

Given this table, how can I compare two rows and identify how `DomainAdminID` changed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
if($this->isChanged('DomainAdminID') {
  ...
  ...
}
```

in the `onBeforeWrite()` function on your object to detect if the id has changed.

If you want to know the new and old values for `DomainAdminID` use [getChangedFields()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataObject.html#_getChangedFields)

Answer (score 0):

Where the DataObjects are in the system and ID 1 and 2 you could read both DataObjects and then compare the arrays of the raw data...

```
array_diff(MyObject::get()->ByID(1)->toMap(),MyObject::get()->ByID(2)->toMap());
```

http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-DataObject.html#_toMap
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php